# Iterate over an interface element of an Interface

Tags: typescript, types

Suppose I have the interfaces:

```
export interface Animals {
   animals: Animal[]
};

export interface Animal {
    name: string,
    age: number
};
```

And I wish to iterate over the animals property of Animals. This is the code I tried suppose I have valid JSON:

```
Animals: Animals = JSONObject.animals;
Animals.animals.forEach((animal, index) => {
    console.log(`Animal Number ${index + 1}`);
    console.log(animal);
});
```

I get the following error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')`.

**EDIT:**
JSON is of the form,

```
"animals": [
    {
        "name":"Cat",
        "age":12
    },
    {
        "name":"Dog",
        "age":7
    }
]
```

Comment: That error is a runtime error, so apparently `JSONObject.Animals` is not what you think it is (and what you've told typescript it is). Can you show us how `JSONObject` is defined?

Comment: `Animals: Animals`  looks odd too before the `=`.

Comment: @NicholasTower updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const Animals: Animals = JSONObject.animals;
Animals.animals.forEach(/* ... */)
```

You are drilling into `.animals` twice. Once in the first assignment, and again on the second line.

You only want to do that once.

```
const Animals: Animals = JSONObject;
Animals.animals.forEach(/* ... */)
```